# Shared library crash when project compiled with -O1 optimization flag

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries, compiler-optimization, abi

### Issue:

I am connecting new shared library to project. It is loaded with run-time dynamic linking. 
This new shared library is calling another shared libraries.

If project is compiled with `-O0` flag - everything works fine.
If project is compiled with `-O1` flag - libraries which are called by this new library are getting

> Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()

Crash is always associated with `std::string`, `basic_string` or `std::basic_stringbuf`.

### What was chcecked:

Valgrind does not show any problems in application before crash.

I have tried to:

- Change lib from run-time dynamic linking to load time dynamic linking
- Check if lib was compiled with the same gcc as mine (`4.4.7`) - it seems that it was, at least grep found GCC 4.4.7 in .so file.

### Backtraces

From Valgrind run: Core dump stack have various bottom parts, but upper parts typically looks like:

```
==46601== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==46601==    at 0x4C287CA: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:507)
==46601==    by 0xF5BE9A6: std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==46601==    by 0xF5C2AB4: std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==46601==    by 0xF5A8C7F: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==46601==    by 0xF5A8E25: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==46601==    by 0xF5BC43D: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
.......
==46601==  Address 0xf81a2c0 is 0 bytes inside data symbol "_ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE"
```

```
==46601== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==46601==    at 0x4C287CA: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:507)
==46601==    by 0xF5C4564: std::string::assign(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==46601==    by 0x21632E52: operator= (basic_string.h:511)
==46601==    by 0x21632E52: str (sstream:129)
==46601==    by 0x21632E52: str (sstream:557)
.........
==46601==  Address 0xf81a2c0 is 0 bytes inside data symbol "_ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE"
```

```
==46601== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==46601==    at 0x4C287CA: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:507)
==46601==    by 0x2308A103: _M_dispose (basic_string.h:236)
==46601==    by 0x2308A103: ~basic_string (basic_string.h:503)
.......
==46601==  Address 0x67b2c0 is 0 bytes inside data symbol "_ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE@@GLIBCXX_3.4"
```

**Edit:**

`D_GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING` macro helped a bit.

Now 

`my project -O1` : `so.file -O0` works

`my project -O1` : `so.file -O1` fails

### Question

I don't have code of these libraries.
I wonder what else can I do to solve this problem.
What should be next steps in investigation?

Comment: You cannot rule out that your code may have bugs that only get exposed when optimizations are used.  Thus unless we have your code, we cannot conclude this has to do with libraries, optimizations, etc.

Comment: I do not have code of these direct and indirectly used libs. My part of stack ends 10 levels below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got 3-rd pt library source and it turned out that it also does dlopen and following bug occures: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42679

Answer (score 0):

> What should be next steps in investigation?

You should start debugging.  Often bugs "get away it" at `-O0` only to hit hard when optimization is cranked up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Because i don't know your code i can only guess.

I assume you created some kind of object used only by your shared library. Probably some kind of boilerplate. You pass that to your shared lib and it does something with it and deletes it afterwards.

Because you never read this variable in your own code there is a high chance the compiler optimizes it away.

To resolve your issue you have to find that specific variable and mark it with `volatile` to prevent it form being optimized away.

I wish you good luck.

Comment: Shared library crashes when calling an ```Init()``` method, without passing anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ c++filt _ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage
```

`_S_empty_rep_storage` is declared as:

```
// The following storage is init'd to 0 by the linker, resulting
// (carefully) in an empty string with one reference.
static size_type _S_empty_rep_storage[];
```

And defined as:

```
  // Linker sets _S_empty_rep_storage to all 0s (one reference, empty string)
  // at static init time (before static ctors are run).
  template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
    typename basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type
    basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage[
    (sizeof(_Rep_base) + sizeof(_CharT) + sizeof(size_type) - 1) /
      sizeof(size_type)];
```

Looks like the shared library you load has another (older) definition of `_S_empty_rep_storage`. In the older versions of the GNU C++ library `_S_empty_rep_storage` used to be dynamically allocated and this is why that shared library tries to do `delete _S_empty_rep_storage` and crashes.

A fix would be to recompile the shared library against the C++ library you use with the same C++ compiler and linker options.